# how to set group by and order by for custom model collection query in magento 2.3.4

Tags: collection, model, magento2.3.4

```
$Custommodel=$this->mycustommodelFactory->create();

$collection = $Custommodel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("customer_id",$customerid);

$collection->getSelect()->group('product_id')->order("viewed_date DESC");
```

while implement this way i getting wrong ordered records

**what mistake there??**

> here this query runing magento SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `wac_viewed_products` AS `main_table` WHERE (`customer_id` = '4') GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY `viewed_date` DESC

Comment: Can you do `->__toString()` to see what query is running and then try in MySQL console directly to see if what you are getting is what is expected?

Comment: getting error for that query

Comment: what error you are getting? the script seems to generate correct query

Comment: i fixed this using MAX(column_name) and thanks to all who cmds this question

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code,

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
           ->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)
           ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Enable');

$collection->getSelect()->group('posts_id')->order('id DESC');
```

Comment: checked with this...

updated question plz check